# When Toggle, spacing decreases

Tags: jquery, html, css, button, toggle

does anyone know how I can stop the toggle effect from causing extra spacing to appear when toggling? The toggle does not allow my content spacing to remain the same.  Currently I toggle and when the content is not showing the spacing decreases, then increase when the toggling content displays.  Below I added a basic code I did. Thanks!!

```
<div class="button_border"><button onclick="myFunction()">Transcript</button></div>
<div id="content">
</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#mytranscript").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: There is nothing called **mytranscript**, so from this piece of code nothing is clear about what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery toggle() method hides things by switching the element's display: property to "none."  Per the CSS spec, the element is removed and other elements re-flow to take up its space.

You want to use the CSS visibility: hidden property instead.  So it would look like this:

```
<div class="button_border"><button onclick="myFunction()">Transcript</button></div>
<div id="content">
</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(){
      if ( $(this).css('visibility') == 'hidden' )
         $(this).css('visibility','visible');
      else
         $(this).css('visibility','hidden');
    });
});
</script>
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone) is a nice explanation of the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none.